# Apache -> Proxy Server and Web Server

Tags: apache, proxy, webserver

How do I have to understand the mod_proxy of apache?

Does it mean that the apache server wiht mod_proxy activated is only a proxy server and I have to set up a new webserver where the proxy will send data?

Or does it mean that the apache webserver is still a webserver wrapped around with the ability of an proxy server. So that the proxy interface will deliver data to the web server in it?!?!

Sorry but I can't describe it in an easier way. Hopefully someone knows what I mean.

with regards
Matthias

Comment: What problem are you actually trying to solve?

Comment: I think this belongs to serverfault.com

Answer (score 1):

What [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_proxy.html) does if that if user U talks to server A then a rewrite in server A can refer to server B as a [proxy].  This is different to an internal redirect which is handled internally in apache or a 30x redirect which is passed back to U's broswer to do.  Here

```
REQUEST   U -> A -> B
RESPONSE  B -> A -> U
```

So the fact that B has actually responded is largely hidden from U.

There is a performance hit on A in having to manage this as Apache (unlike nginx, say) isn't really optimised for this task, but sometimes the flexibility to do this is useful.

This is not a caching proxy though when combined with the mod_*_cache modules, Apache can be used to do this, though I don't know of any serious webadmin who would dream of using Apache like this -- it's not its sweet spot.